# How can I configure incremental search to put my cursor at the start of whitespace rather than the end?

Tags: search, whitespace, isearch

I just installed a new version of Emacs (24.3.1 through Fedora). For some reason, when I use `C-s` to search for a single space character, it jumps my cursor to the *end* of contiguous spaces rather than the beginning. For example, if I'm at the start of this line:

```
type thread_id        = ...
```

and do `C-s SPC`, all the spaces in the buffer are highlighted. But when I advance up to the spaces before the `=`, my cursor is immediately positioned *on* the `=` rather than after the *first* space (ie two positions after the end of `thread_id`).

How can I get my cursor to be at the first single character rather than the end of the range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Emacs Manual (section [Special Isearch](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Special-Isearch.html)) says this:

> By default, incremental search performs lax space matching: each space, or sequence of spaces, matches any sequence of one or more spaces in the text. Hence, "`foo bar`" matches "`foo bar`", "`foo  bar`", "`foo   bar`", and so on (but not "`foobar`"). More precisely, Emacs matches each sequence of space characters in the search string to a regular expression specified by the variable `search-whitespace-regexp`. For example, to make spaces match sequences of newlines as well as spaces, set it to `"[[:space:]\n]+"`.
>
> To toggle lax space matching, type `M-s <SPC>` (`isearch-toggle-lax-whitespace`). To disable this feature entirely, change `search-whitespace-regexp` to `nil`; then each space in the search string matches exactly one space.

So, set `search-whitespace-regexp` to `nil` (or set `isearch-lax-whitespace` to `nil` -- it seems to have the same effect).

Comment: Yep, that seems to solve it. Odd that I've never run into this before if it's been a default...

Comment: It was not the default behavior in older versions of Emacs.